# Comparing arrays to get the list of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a list of first arrays

```
const a = [{id:1, value:'apple'}, {id:2, value: 'ball'},{id:3, value: 'cat'}]
```

I have another array of ids

```
const ids = [1,2]
```

Now, I need to get the  list of array values from `a`, which has id listed in ids array. Expected result:

```
const b =  [{id:1, value:'apple'}, {id:2, value: 'ball'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
a.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id));
```

```js
const a = [{id:1, value:'apple'}, {id:2, value: 'ball'}];

const ids = [1,2];

const result = a.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Set` from the array of ids and use `Array#filter` with `Set#has` (which runs in `O(1)` time) for enhanced performance.

```js
const a = [{id:1, value:'apple'}, {id:2, value: 'ball'},{id:3, value: 'cat'}]
const ids = [1,2]
const idSet = new Set(ids);
const res = a.filter(({id})=>idSet.has(id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understand you correctly here, you wish to get the `value` params from `a` for each of the records that has a matching `id` in the `ids` collection?

```
let results = a.filter(node=>ids.indexOf(node.id) !== -1);
```

To break down the `Array.prototype.filter` command:

`a.filter` is functionally telling the compiler to iterate the `a` collection (like a `for` loop); although the only records that come back OUT of it are returned when a truthy value is returned from its callback (the function being applied after the `node=>` bit).

`node` is the temporary variable assigned to the active index being examined in the iteration.

`ids.indexOf(...)` it requesting the numeric index of `node.id` in the collection. If `node.id` is present *nowhere* in the collection, `indexOf` returns a `-1`.

So, taken all together: "loop through `a`, and for each of the objects contained therein, test each one against `ids`, and return either `true` or `false` depending if it was found (some value OTHER than `-1`) or not (`-1`). Array. filter will automagically display only those whose results were true.